# Access request payload parameters in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using a spring form and in my form I have used angularjs. But when request is sent through angularjs I am not able to access the form values in controller.

Angularjs code

```
function submitController($scope, $http) {
      alert("function called");
           $scope.submit = function()
            {
             var formData = $('#formId').serialize();
             $http.post('searchPatientResult', formData).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.user = data;
                    console.log($scope.user);

                });
    };
       }
```

Form code

```
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Patient Id</label>
 <div class="col-sm-2"><form:input path="patientId" class="form-control" type="number" /></div> 

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><form:input path="name" class="form-control" type="text" /></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><form:input path="age" class="form-control" style="width:100px; float: left;" type="number" /><span style="line-height: 30px; padding-left: 10px;
                                    ">years</span></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-offset-10"> <input class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='button' value='Search'  ng-click="submit()" /></div>
```

Request screen shot
[image]

Comment: Please include what your request looks like in your question (use Chrome Developer Tools), and your controller definition

Comment: @Neil McGuigan i have added the request screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your angular code needs to be correct,please try this

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Patient Id</label>
 <div class="col-sm-2"><form:input path="patientId" class="form-control" data-ng-model="patient.id" type="number" /></div> 

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><form:input path="name" data-ng-model="patient.name" class="form-control" type="text" /></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><form:input path="age" data-ng-model="patient.age" class="form-control" style="width:100px; float: left;" type="number" /><span style="line-height: 30px; padding-left: 10px;
                                    ">years</span></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-offset-10"> <input class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='button' value='Search'  ng-click="submit(patient)" /></div>
```

And controller

```
$scope.submit = function(patientData)
            {
             $http.post('searchPatientResult', patientData).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.user = data;
                    console.log($scope.user);

                });
    };
```

you can access it in controller like

```
public void saveUser(@RequestBody Map map){


    final String name = map.get("name");
}
```